# Variable category conditions in ggplot2 density plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, conditional-statements

In R, I would like multiple individual density plots, preferably using the ggplot2 package. The data frame has variable V1, which has multiple levels (ie see data example below).

```
V1 V2
1  5
1  4 
1  2
2  3
2  8
2  6
3  5
3  9
```

How could I use qplot or ggplot to create density plots for V1=1 V1=2 and V1=3, in which V2 values are tied to the values of V1 (ie the density plot for V1=1 only accounts for V2=(5, 4, 2))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=V2)) +
             geom_density(aes(group=V1, colour=V1, fill=V1))+
             theme_bw()
```

#### Update

You could use `facet_wrap` to create individual plot

```
 ggplot(df1, aes(x=V2))+
              geom_density(aes(colour=V1, fill=V1))+
              facet_wrap(~V1)+
              theme_bw()
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), V2 = c(5, 4, 
 2, 3, 8, 6, 5, 9, 10)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), row.names = c(NA, 
9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Would I be able to incorporate facets into this so that each density plot is separate (there are many levels of V1)?

Comment: When I try that, I get the following: 

"Error in layout_base(data, vars, drop = drop) : 
 At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting"

Comment: @Warppp I didn't get the error in the example you showed or in the modified example I created

Comment: Yes, interesting. I tried with the dataframe I provided and it works well. I will play around with my other data. Thank you so much for the help! It has definitely brought me a step closer.

Comment: @Warpp Could you show the data that is not working.  You could share that in dropbox

Comment: Actually, no need to! Once I attached the data, it worked perfectly. Thank you for the excellent help!